# Material UI Snackbar Won't dismiss

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, snackbar

I'm trying to dismiss the snackbar by click away and by clicking on the "X" on the snackbar but it just won't go away, it should go away after 10s but it doesn't! I don't what i'm missing

```
const Footer = () => {

const [snackbarState, setSnackbarState] = useState({
  open: false,
  Transition: Slide,
  });

  const [subscribeSuccess, setSubSuccessMsg] = useState({
    success: false,
    msg: "",
    });

    const handleSuccessClose = (event, subscribeSuccess) => {
      if (subscribeSuccess === 'clickaway') {
          return;
      }
      setSubSuccessMsg({ success: true, msg: ""});
      };

      return (
        {subscribeSuccess &&
          <Snackbar
              position="static"
              TransitionComponent={snackbarState.Transition}
              anchorOrigin={{
              vertical: "top",
              horizontal: "center",
              }}
              open={subscribeSuccess.success}
              // message={registerErr.msg}
              autoHideDuration={10000}
              onClose={handleSuccessClose}
              sx={{ width: {xs: "100%", sm: "100%", 
              md: "100%", lg: "70%"} }}>
                  <Alert
                  onClose={handleSuccessClose} 
                  severity="success" 
                  sx={{ width: '100%',
                          '& .MuiAlert-message':{
                          textAlign:"center", width:"inherit" }}}>
                          {subscribeSuccess.msg}
                  </Alert>
          </Snackbar>
      }
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set `open` prop of `Snackbar` to `false` in onClose handler. in your case set your `subscribeSuccess.success` to false

```
const handleSuccessClose = (event, subscribeSuccess) => {
      if (subscribeSuccess === 'clickaway') {
          return;
      }
      setSubSuccessMsg({ success: false, msg: ""});
      };
```

(dont know what that is condition purpose)